# get PreStop lifecycle hook execution results

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, lifecycle-hook

i'm trying to find out how to get `preStop` execution result for debugging purposes.

I'm creating a pod (not part of a deployment) with the following lifecycle definition:

```
   terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
   lifecycle:
      preStop:
        exec:
          command:
          - /bin/sh
          - -c
          - "echo trying post_stop;sleep 60"
```

when I ran it I can see it waiting 60 seconds but I cannot see any events for `preStop` hook being triggers not when I run `kubectl get events` and not when I run `kubectl describe pod <my-pod>`
more then that I would love to know where the logs of the hook is being written, I tried to run `kubectl logs <my-pod> -f` but I did not see any logs there

Comment: have you looked at echoing to the terminationMessagePath?

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/determine-reason-pod-failure/

Defaults:     terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File

Comment: I cannot get the pod's yaml after he was deleted. so writing to /dev/termination-log did not help in this case (i'm using k8s 1.11)

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right path with `kubectl describe`, check out the following location: `/dev/termination-log` see also the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/determine-reason-pod-failure/#writing-and-reading-a-termination-message).

Comment: I cannot get the pod's yaml after he was deleted. so both `kubectl describe` and writing to /dev/termination-log did not help in this case (i'm using k8s 1.11)

Comment: You have the pod name? Also, not writing to but reading from that location (within the pod). I wrote about it, here: https://blog.openshift.com/kubernetes-pods-life/